# 60M+ InnoDB table simple query performance HELP

Tags: mysql, innodb, optimization, query-performance

I know it is a repeated question but really need help here.
What can I do to improve the performance of this query?
Considering that I have no freedom to change system variables/configs :(
Thanks in advance!!!

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `pinc_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pinc_codigo` char(10) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pinc_id`,`pinc_codigo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT pinc_codigo FROM t1 WHERE pinc_codigo='somechar10';
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t1 | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 14      | NULL | 69000333 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+----------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT pinc_codigo FROM t1 WHERE pinc_codigo='somechar10';
+-------------+
| pinc_codigo |
+-------------+
| somechar10  |
+-------------+
1 row in set (30.41 sec)
```

Comment: Create an index on `pinc_codigo`

Comment: What is the purpose of the query, is it to find out whether 'somechar10' exists or not?

Comment: When I see this, I normally assume that the OP's query is about something more like SELECT <my_field_list>, <my_index_field> FROM My_Table.... though it's always good to check.

Comment: Hi guys, tkx !
@Lennart yes it is.
a_horse_with_no_name I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to Johan's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213235/mysql-covering-vs-composite-vs-column-index), particularly the bit about covering indexes in InnoDB.

My understanding of what he has written is that you should change your table definition to the following

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `pinc_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pinc_codigo` char(10) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pinc_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;

ALTER TABLE `t1` ADD INDEX `t1_idx_pinc_cogido` (`pinc_cogido`);
```

Could you do this on test and report back?

[EDIT]

It's not very clear from your post, but is pinc_cogido unique? If so, you should use

```
ALTER TABLE `t1` ADD UNIQUE INDEX `t1_uidx_pinc_cogido` (`pinc_cogido`);
```

(also, slight change - it's good practice to name all your indexes)

```
PRIMARY KEY `t1_pk_pinc_id' (`pinc_id`);
```

[EDIT2]

In answer to this

```
Thankx @Veráce ! No, no other fields in the table just this two
```

Is there any point in having a table with 1 field? Could you explain the thinking here? Is your pinc_cogido field a lookup?

The table structure should not be IMHO, since pinc_cogido is both UNIQUE and NOT NULL.

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `pinc_codigo` char(10) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `other_field1` ....,
  `other_field2` ....,
  `...`,
  PRIMARY KEY `t1_pk_pinc_cogido` (`pinc_cogido`);
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;
```

Comment: Hello @Vérace !
Sure ! I'll make the test and report back here.
Additional intel:
The data in pinc_codigo is UNIQUE so I'll change the table and post results here.

I was trying to make use of the clustered that's why I did the PRIMARY KEY (`pinc_id`,`pinc_codigo`)

Comment: Read [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-index-types.html) about clustered indexes. Another question - if pinc_codigo is both UNIQUE and NOT NULL, then why not make it the PRIMARY KEY? Is my assumption about other fields true (see comment to Lennart)?

Comment: Maybe this?

`CREATE TABLE t1 (
  pinc_codigo CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  pinc_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (pinc_codigo),
  UNIQUE INDEX pinc_codigo_UNIQUE (pinc_codigo ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX pinc_id_UNIQUE (pinc_id ASC));
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;`

Comment: Major problem here as far as I can see. If pinc_cogido is UNIQUE and NOT NULL, then it should be the PRIMARY KEY. pinc_id has no function whatsoever. Check my edit (2) of my answer for my new table proposition. Is my assumption about there being other fields in the table correct?

Comment: Thankx @Veráce !
No, no other fields in the table just this two.

Comment: yes its a lookup.
It's a promotional printed number.
I need to lookup if it exist's and if it's not used (using an auxiliar table) and then make some another stuff.

Comment: Fine - now I think I understand. Why do you want to add this pinc_id field? It servers **no** purpose. Just make the only field in the table its PRIMARY KEY. What is the cardinality of pinc_cogido (how many values)? It must be reasonably large if it took 30 seconds to return a value as per your original question.

Comment: 69000333 rows now with a chance to grow.
The pinc_id was only for identification, but I think it is terribly wrong to have this field, in this case.

Comment: Can you use the table structure I suggested to perform your original query and let us know the results?